# How can I force some pages to end in a slash [.htaccess]

Tags: .htaccess

This is a multi-site problem.  I have a lot of sites with .htaccess files with multiple line similar to:

```
rewriterule ^(page-one|page-two|page-three)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This means that both www.domain.com/page-one and www.domain.com/page-one/ will both load www.domain.com/index.php?page=page-one

However I'm always told that it is good SEO practice to make sure you use only one URL per page so what I'd like to do make www.domain.com/page-one to redirect to www.domain.com/page-one/ via the .htaccess file.

Please note the answer I'm **NOT** looking for is to remove the ?$ from the end of the line as that will just cause www.domain.com/page-one to become a 404 link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a snippet to force everything to end with a slash

```
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTTP redirect to send users who use the "wrong" URL to the correct one. You could for example use:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R]
```

before your own RewriteRule.

Beware, though: this will also add slashes to URLs that end in a filename. If you have such URLs, you have to put exceptions for them before the redirect.

See also the [FAQ entry on trailing slashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ-E.html#set-servername) and the [example page for mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#trailingslash)!

Answer (score 1):

*Untested*, but can't you just do this?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/
RewriteRule ^(page-one|page-two|page-three)?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```