# .htaccess do not rewrite if there are $_GET vars

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I am trying to make sure that all my urls are corrected to end in a forward slash so if a user types

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blogPost
```

it would become

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blogPost/
```

I found the answer to this question here [How can I force some pages to end in a slash [.htaccess]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324381/how-can-i-force-some-pages-to-end-in-a-slash-htaccess/#answer-1747056) (Thanks Andrew G. Johnson).

This solution works almost perfectly apart from when there are $_GET vars. So when the url has $_GET vars like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blogPost/^start=10
```

the htaccess rewrites it to be

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blogPost/^start=10/
```

which causes an error.

The original code copied from the stack overflow question looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

So to get htaccess to ignore urls when there are $_GET vars I tried adding a RewriteCond to the above code to check the REQUEST_URI for a ^ (because on this site $_GET vars start with a ^ instead of a ?) And I have tried all of the following but nothing works. Can anyone point me in the right direction

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^\^]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\^]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^\^])
```

(I also tried the above with {QUERY_STRING})

Comment: `^start=10` is **not** a query string. This may be some internal handling of your php scripts, that translate this into `$_GET` variables, but this definitely is part of URI, not query-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it so URI's with a `^` are ignored:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\^
```

But it doesn't address when there's no slash *before* it, which this separate rule should take care of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]\^
RewriteRule ^(.*)\^(.*)$ /$1/^$2 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\^  RewriteCond%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]` This code still appends a forward slash to the $_GET vars. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @TheoKouzelis When I put those rules in a blank htaccesss file in a vanilla apache 2.2 install, it doesn't redirect for any request containing a `^`.

Comment: tested it on a different system and it works great. Thanks alot for your help